# Latex subtables side by side

Tags: latex, subfigure

I have been trying to setup those subtables as 2x5, but it is generated as one subtable per row.
I have tried minipage, parbox, resizebox and nothing I know could pack 5 subtables into a single row. The code is shortened to 2x2 example.
I would appreciate any sugestions.
Thanks :)

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{\textcolor{red}{Confusion matrices for well-known pretrained convolutional neural networks}}

\begin{subtable}[h!]{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{60} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & 7\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{82} & 6\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 99
\end{tabular}
\subcaption{DenseNet 121}
\label{tab:conf_densenet121}
\end{subtable}

\hfill

\begin{subtable}[h!]{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{65} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & 5\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{86} & 3\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 101
\end{tabular}

\subcaption{DenseNet 201}
\label{tab:conf_densenet201}
\end{subtable}

\vskip\baselineskip

\begin{subtable}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{63} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 5\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 101
\end{tabular}
\caption{ResNet50 V2}
\label{tab:conf_resnet50v2}
\end{subtable}

\hfill

\begin{subtable}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & 4\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 102
\end{tabular}
\caption{ResNet152 V2}
\label{tab:conf_resnet152v2}
\end{subtable}

\label{tab:confusion}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: The empty lines in your code act as paragraph breaks and thus will force new lines.

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] which includes all the packages etc. necessary to compile your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
I have substituted `subfig` with the actively maintained package `subcaption`; the last date `subfig` was updated is in 2005.

Here's the new code

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=12pt}
\captionsetup[subtable]{position=top,aboveskip=3pt}

\newcommand\actual{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}}}
\newcommand\predicted{\multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted}}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}
\kant[1-5]

Reference to the Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet}.

References to sub-tables:
\begin{itemize}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_densenet121}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_densenet201}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_densenet2011}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet50v2}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet152v2}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet50v22}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet152v22}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet152v23}
\end{itemize}

\begin{table*}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.35}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \caption{\textcolor{red}{Confusion matrices for well-known pretrained convolutional neural networks}}
  \label{tab:conf_resnet}
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[DenseNet 121]{%
    \label{tab:conf_densenet121}%
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 60 & 5  & 7 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 8  & 82 & 6 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 6  & 3  & 99
    \end{tabular}}
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[DenseNet 201]{%
    \label{tab:conf_densenet201}%
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 65 & 2  & 5 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 7  & 86 & 3 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 4  & 3  & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[DenseNet 201]{%
    \label{tab:conf_densenet2011}%
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 65 & 2  & 5 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 7  & 86 & 3 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 4  & 3  & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{\fill}

  \vspace{12pt}
  
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet50 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet50v2}
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 63 & 4  & 5 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 5  & 90 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 3  & 4  & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet152 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet152v2}
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 62 & 6  & 4 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 7  & 88 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 2  & 4  & 102
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{\fill}

  \vspace{12pt}
  
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet50 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet50v22}
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 63 & 4  & 5 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 5  & 90 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 3  & 4  & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet152 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet152v22}
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 62 & 6  & 4 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 7  & 88 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 2  & 4  & 102
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet152 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet152v23}
    \begin{tabular}{c *4{c|}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \predicted \\
                           &                      & K  & C  & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \actual              & K                    & 62 & 6  & 4 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & C                    & 7  & 88 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                           & R                    & 2  & 4  & 102
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{\fill}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

If each table is going to be exactly the same, you can just use a simple pattern:

`\hfill` table `\hfill` table `\hfill` etc.

If they are going to be different, you can use `tabular` instead. Remember, if you want to place elements horizontally, you can't add extra empty lines. It causes LaTeX to start new paragraphs.

I created a grid of 3/2/3 tables. `\subfloat[]{}` is also a convenient macro to make sub-captions; it is defined in [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig). Any `sub-` related macro is only required if you want to make a reference to each individual table. If you don't, you can safely remove `\subfloat` along with [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig).

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=12pt}
\captionsetup[subtable]{position=top,captionskip=2pt}


\begin{document}
\section{The first section}
\kant[1-5]

Reference to the Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet}.

References to sub-tables:
\begin{itemize}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_densenet121}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_densenet201}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_densenet2011}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet50v2}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet152v2}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet50v22}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet152v22}
\item Table~\ref{tab:conf_resnet152v23}
\end{itemize}

\begin{table*}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \caption{\textcolor{red}{Confusion matrices for well-known pretrained convolutional neural networks}}
  \label{tab:conf_resnet}
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[DenseNet 121]{%
    \label{tab:conf_densenet121}%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{60} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & 7\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{82} & 6\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 99
    \end{tabular}}
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[DenseNet 201]{%
    \label{tab:conf_densenet201}%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{65} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & 5\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{86} & 3\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[DenseNet 201]{%
    \label{tab:conf_densenet2011}%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{65} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & 5\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{86} & 3\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{\fill}

  \vspace{12pt}
  
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet50 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet50v2}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{63} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 5\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet152 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet152v2}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & 4\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 102
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{\fill}

  \vspace{12pt}
  
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet50 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet50v22}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{63} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 5\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 101
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet152 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet152v22}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & 4\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 102
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[ResNet152 V2]{%
    \label{tab:conf_resnet152v23}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
      \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{K} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & 4\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88} & 1\\ \cline{2-5} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 102
    \end{tabular}}%
  \hspace{\fill}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```